# Impossible error... concurrency issue? NextJs / Node HTTP Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, next.js

I am having a problem that is supposed not to happen:

[image]

See `initialUserState` is being set depending on the result of a ternary operation. However, this operation should return false here (as there's no `user` property in `context` object. (You can see it in the debugger below)

What could be possibly going on here?

The data is from a previous request in a NextJS application (I am using Firefox and Firefox Private mode). This only happens when the request are quick next to each other. So I think this  is a concurrency issue, but can't understand why javascript would fail with that condition. How `initialUserState` is holding that value if I am declaring it again here.

```
import {userInitialState} from "./UserContext";
import {listInitialState} from "./ListContext";
import {createContext, useState} from "react";

/**
 * Sets the initial application context
 */
export default class ApplicationContext {

    userContext;
    listContext;

    /**
     * Will set the initial application state.
     * @param context
     */
    constructor(context) {
        let initialUserState = context.hasOwnProperty('user') ? context.user : userInitialState;
        const userContextUpdater = () => {
            let [state, setState] = useState({...initialUserState})
            return [state, setState];
        }
        this.userContext = createContext(userContextUpdater);

        let initialListState = context.hasOwnProperty('list') ? context.list : listInitialState;
        const listContextUpdater = () => {
            let [state, setState] = useState({...initialListState})
            return [state, setState];
        }
        this.listContext = createContext(listContextUpdater);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the UserContext
     * @returns {*}
     */
    getUserContext = () => {
        return this.userContext;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the List context
     * @returns {*}
     */
    getListContext = () => {
        return this.listContext;
    }
}
```

_app.js

```
import ApplicationContext from "../lib/Context/ApplicationContext";
import {useContext} from "react";

export default function RankerApp({Component, pageProps}) {
    const applicationContext = new ApplicationContext(pageProps);
    const ListContext = applicationContext.getListContext();
    const UserContext = applicationContext.getUserContext();

    const [listState, setListState] = useContext(ListContext)();
    const [userState, setUserState] = useContext(UserContext)();

    return (
        <ListContext.Provider value={[listState, setListState]}>
            <UserContext.Provider value={[userState, setUserState]}>
                <Component {...pageProps} applicationContext={applicationContext}/>
            </UserContext.Provider>
        </ListContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

UserContext.js

```
export const userInitialState = {
    currentUserId: undefined,
    users: {},
}
```

This is driving me nuts, it looks like it is some kind of concurrency issue, I can't explain it otherwise, as this doesn't happen if the request are spaced in time

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems I got bitten by object references.

This was before:

[image]

This is the fix

[image]

So here I assigned to the `returnContext['user']` a reference to `userInitialState`

And then modified it right below.

Since for some reason my NextJS app is persisting things (I don't know if this is because of being a compiled server, but the variables inside Pages remain if I put a counter), this value was also persisting.